# What is the meaning of "spring reloaded"?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

What does "spring reloaded" mean? Does it mean "spring has come again" or "people are ready for spring this year again" or anything else?

"Spring reloaded" is used in some blogs or websites as a title of an article explaining what Easter is, weather of spring this year, spring clothes etc.

Here are websites I found:

http://www.encorepub.com/spring-reloaded/

https://presentlywandering.wordpress.com/2016/04/16/spring-reloaded/

Comment: This kind of expression is called a _play on words._ This particular one is a play on the term [**_spring loaded._**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/spring-loaded) (A non-native speaker might not be familiar with this expression...)

Answer (score 1):

Your phrase

> Spring reloaded

is used in your examples to mean the refreshening or restarting of Spring.

That Spring has come again.

In your first example, the church is saying every year Spring comes and there is a rebirth, that nature gets *reloaded* after being loaded the previous Springtime and spending itself through the year until a dormant winter's sleep.

Your second example, uses the premise of Spring being rebirth, but because of weather conditions Spring had a "false start" and the second time it is "reloading".

Both mean to replenish and refreshen but the first is annually and the second is seasonally.

Comment: Are you familiar with the term [**_spring loaded?_**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/spring-loaded)

Comment: Yes, but the OP's both examples talk about the season and not the mechanism, eventhough her phrase is a play on the mechanism.

Comment: That's why it's a play on words. That's the point; it's why the writer used the phrase.